# Protractor can't click on embedded <span> inside <a> element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have two  embedded `<span>` elements inside an `<a>` element. I need to trigger a click event on the second `<span>`. The `by.id` method on the `id` classes I created didn't trigger a click.  I also tried `by.binding` and that didn't work. help please?

The code:

```
<div class="add-player">
  <a href class="btn" data-ng-if="!currentUser.isAuthenticated && !vm.hasPendingInvitation">
    <span>Add Player</span>
  </a>
  <a href class="btn" id="invite" data-ng-if="currentUser.isAuthenticated && !vm.hasPendingInvitation">
    <span id="invite-player">Add Player</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can play around with locators:

```
$("div.add-player a span").click();
$("#invite-player").click();
element(by.xpath("//span[. = 'Add Player']")).click();
```

We can also [wait for the element to be visible](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.visibilityOf):

```
var addPlayer = $("div.add-player a span"),
    EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(addPlayer), 5000);
addPlayer.click();
```

We can also try clicking *via JavaScript*:

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", addPlayer.getWebElement());
```

Or via [`browser.actions()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions):

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(addPlayer).click().perform();
```

Or, [scroll into view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) before clicking:

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", addPlayer.getWebElement());
addPlayer.click();
```

---

You can also [filter](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) the visible element matching a locator:

```
var addPlayer = $$("#invite-player").filter(function (elm) {
    return elm.isDisplayed();
}).first();
addPlayer.click();
```

Comment: I tried ```$("#invite-player").click();```  and got this error ```WARNING - more than one element found for locator By.cssSelector("#claim-this-profile") - the first result will be used```  Then I tried ```$("#invite-player").last().click();``` then this error  ```TypeError: undefined is not a function```  There is only one ```id="invite-player"```tag on the angular page so I don't understand why its warning ```more than one element found for locator By.cssSelector("#invite-player")```

Comment: @C.J.delFrias this probably means that there are actually several elements matching the `id`. Assuming there is only one visible, please see the option below the line in the answer. Thanks.