# TimeOut While waiting for element with locator

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, protractor, e2e-testing

I am trying to test below code:

```
<div name="userElem" *ngFor="let user of users ; let i=index">
    <div class="list-group-item" id="user-{{i}}" (click)='selectUser(user)' [style.backgroundColor]="user?._id==selectedUser?._id ? '#F0F0EE' : 'white'">
        <div *ngIf="user?._id==selectedUser?._id">      
            <div class="pull-right">        
                <a  id="delete-user-{{i}}" (click)="deleteUser(user._id)">  
                    <i class="fa fa-trash fa-fw"></i>
                </a>
                <a  (click)="editUser(user._id)">
                   <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw"></i>
                </a>
                <a [routerLink]="['/edit',user._id]" name="userLink-{{i}}">
                    <i class="fa fa-eye fa-fw"></i>
                 </a>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

By Using Below E2E Test Case:

```
it('should delete a user', () => {
    page.navigateToUserComponent();  
    let selectUserElem = element(by.id('user-0')).click();   //this event is fired as I can see user getting selected.    
    let deleteUserElem = element(by.id('delete-user-0'));    
    browser.wait(function() {
        return browser.isElementPresent(by.id('delete-user-0'));
    }, 5000);
    expect(deleteUserElem.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();  // if element is present I want to click that element .i.e. delete the first user in array
  });
```

But So Far Not Getting Any Success.

I tried Multiple Approaches as discussed in this link:

[StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561999/protractor-cant-click-on-embedded-span-inside-a-element)

But Couldn't make it work.
any help?

Thanks

Comment: I think id 'delete-user-0' is not constant can you check it once

Comment: @SureshSalloju when my angular2 app runs , inspecting the DOm shows id as : id='delete-user-0''..where delete-user is a string & 0 is a index

Comment: deleteUserElem=element.all(by.css('[name="userElem"]>div>div>div>a)).first() try this

Comment: @SureshSalloju tried this.getting error: `Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 60 seconds & While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, *[name=&quot;userElem&quot;])`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ExpectedConditions`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions) along with `browser.wait()` to make your script wait for certain condition:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var elm = element(by.id('delete-user-0'));

browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(elm), 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identify first delete_user element you can use following xpath.

```
let deleteUserElem = element.all(by.xpath(".//a[contains(@id, 'delete-user-')]")).first();
```

then you can cobine it with the protractor expected condition to wait till the desired web element is present.

```
EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(deleteUserElem),20000, 'element is not visible within the time specified');
```

Comment: Tried this. still no success

Answer (score 0):

Are you using socket.io? There seems to be bug where protractor does not work if you are using socket.io in your app: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11853 .